# Android - To measure the time between the two button clicks

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a button named `Check In`. My aim is on click to change the text and start counting the time. The timer has to stop at the next click. It should give the time taken between the two button clicks.

Comment: my doubt is regarding the usage of Alarm service and normal timer in java.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

On the first click create a variable:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then on the second click you can calculate the difference:

```
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

`difference / 1000` will give you the difference in seconds. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will suggest using `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Documentation says:
`System.currentTimeMillis()` is the standard "wall" clock expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network, so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably.
`elapsedRealtime()` and `elapsedRealtimeNanos()` return the time since the system was booted. This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing.

Answer (score 15):

I think it is better practice to use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead of [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), as `currentTimeMillis()` relies on what time the system's clock is set to, which can be changed.

`nanoTime()`, however, is really designed to measure elapsed time according to the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or create a new `Date` or `GregorianCalendar` instance) on click.

Save it somewhere. On next click do the same. Then compare the times.