# How to measure time between taps up to milliseconds?

Tags: android

I want to measure time between consecutive taps in milliseconds. How can I do this?

Comment: For Each tap get the current time and find the difference between between the lap tap time.

Comment: Use [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - To measure the time betweeen the two button clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965065/android-to-measure-the-time-betweeen-the-two-button-clicks)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
View myView;
long previousClickTime;

...

myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev)
    {
        long temp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (previousClickTime != 0)
        {
            Log.i("MyView", "Time Between Clicks=" + (temp - previousClickTime));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("MyView", "First Click");
        }
        previousClickTime = temp;

        return true;//Note that you can return false, and any underlying Views will then receive this touch event.
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you are trying to detect a double click, try [GuestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#setOnDoubleTapListener%28android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener%29).

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onCLick()` events.

Inside the `onClick()` event. Have your app get the first tap and store the time. Then store the second time and get the difference between the two taps. And just display the difference.

*The code below is very simple and may not be what you are looking for, but i put it there as a very trivial example.*

```
long initialTime = 0;
long endTime = 0;

onClick() {

    if(initialTime == 0){
        initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = endTime - initialTime;
        initialTime = endTime;
        Log.i("your app", "time between click: " + diff);
    }

}
```